Line integral of an exponential
Let $V_1, V_2\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be the vertices of a segment $s$, that is
\begin{equation}
s\triangleq\{z(\alpha) = (V_2-V_1)\,\alpha + V_1 \}_{\alpha\in[0,1]}
\end{equation}
Now let $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a given point and let $R\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ be a covariance matrix. I need to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}I(y)\triangleq \int_s \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lVert y-z \rVert_{R}^2\right) \,\,\mathrm{d}z\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\lVert y-z \rVert_{R}\triangleq \sqrt{(y-z)'R^{-1}(y-z)}
\end{equation}
I'm not sure, but I suspect that it is possible to get an analytical solution. If it can help, I can assume that $R=\sigma_v^2\,I_2$ for a given $\sigma_v$ (while $I_2$ denotes the $2\times2$ identity matrix).
My approach
So far, I've found a numerical approximation (hopefully, without mistakes), but I have to say that I'm not that happy with it. Using the $\alpha$-parametrization, the integral gets the form
\begin{equation}
I(y) = \int_0^1 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lVert y-z(\alpha) \rVert_{R}^2\right) \,\,\lVert \dot{z}(\alpha)\rVert \,\,\mathrm{d}\alpha
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\dot{z}(\alpha)\triangleq\frac{\mathrm{d}z(\alpha)}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}=(V_2-V_1)
\end{equation}
consequently,
\begin{align}
I(y)&=\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert \int_0^1\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lVert y-(V_2-V_1)\alpha-V_1 \rVert_{R}^2\right) \,\, \,\,\mathrm{d}\alpha \\
&=\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert \int_0^1\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lVert (V_2-V_1)\alpha-(y-V_1) \rVert_{R}^2\right) \,\, \,\,\mathrm{d}\alpha \\
\end{align}
at this point I complete the integration by considering the trapezoidal approximation, that is
\begin{align}
I(y)&\approx \lVert V_2-V_1\rVert \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{f(\alpha_{i+1})+f(\alpha_i)}{2} \Delta \alpha\\
f(\alpha) &\triangleq \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lVert (V_2-V_1)\alpha-(y-V_1) \rVert_{R}^2\right)\\
\alpha_i &\triangleq \frac{i-1}{N-1}\\
\Delta \alpha &\triangleq \frac{1}{N-1}
\end{align}
where $N$ is the resolution of the approximation.
Observation
My suspicions arise from the fact that my integral resembles the following one
\begin{equation}
\int \exp\left(cx^2\right)\,x\,\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
which admits an analytical solution.
Question
Is it possible to find an analytical solution for my integral?
